# How to use ACF repeater?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF but the `get_field` option doesn't work when using a repeater field

```
<?php echo get_field('field_name'); ?>
```

Comment: His question, albeit easy to find an answer to with a quick google search, is in fact specific to wordpress. ACF is hugely popular plugin for wordpress.

Comment: @elzi "Third party plugins and themes are off topic" That is the actual reason for this question to be put on hold

Comment: @elzi Please read here ([help/dont-ask]) what's considered to be off topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `have_rows()` loop, then use `get_sub_field`.

ACF provides great documentation, which happens to be the first google result, [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/)

Comment: Elzi, even if it bothers you: Please stay away from comments or answers with Google results. This is seen as rude and the link target will have changed contents in some month. Keep this in mind. Thanks.

Comment: I answered with the official documentation for the plugin, not a Google results page.